# Retrieving a Session value in Laravel returns null

Tags: php, laravel, session, vuejs2, session-variables

I am setting and attempting to retrieve a session value from a Laravel application. A Vue Js frontend is making an API call to a Laravel endpoint which sets the session value. The controller which contains the method for the Laravel endpoint is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
Use Session;

use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function adduser(Request $request) {

        $user = User::where( 'sub', $request->sub )->first();

        if(!$user) {

            $user = new User();

            $user->nickname = $request->nickname;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->sub = $request->sub;
            $user->api_token = $request->api_token;

            $user->save();

        }

        $user->api_token = $request->api_token;
        $user->save();

        return response()
            ->json([
                'done' => $user->api_token
            ]);

    }

    //The endpoint for this method is http://localhost:8000/api/set
    public function setSession(Request $request) {


        $request->session()->put('info', 'testing vue client again');
        Session::save();

        return response()
            ->json([
                'done' => session('info')
            ]);

    }
    //The endpoint for this method is: http://localhost:8000/api/get
    public function getSession(Request $request) {

        $value = $request->session()->get('info');
        return response()
            ->json([
                'done' => $value
            ]);

    }

}
```

The session data is set successfully, however when I try to retrieve this data from the `getSession()` method it returns null. This is the Vue Js/axios code snippet I used to attempt to retrieve the session data

```
axios({
 method: 'get',
 url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/get',


}).then((res) => {
console.log(res.data)
})
```

How do I solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Routes from routes/api.php file by default doesn't have `StartSession` middleware because api calls considered as stateless. You can add this middleware with`EncryptCookies` to api middleware group in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file like this, with exact sequence:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Works for me. Also, think you can setup `api` group exactly as `web` group in your case.

And don't forget set your session variable again with new configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already done as you have suggested here and that is why the session was set in the first place. The challenge I have now is retrieving the session data which for some reason returns null

Answer (score 1):

I had reproduce the issue and seems problem with cookies.
This did the trick for me:

app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php

```
protected $except = [
    'laravel_session',
];
```

Change `laravel_session` to your `config('session.cookie')` value.

See [Session ID changes on refresh (Laravel 5.4 + AngularJS 1.6)](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/session-id-changes-on-refresh-laravel-54-angularjs-16)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just went to the app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php file and I find that the `$except` array is empty. It is like this; ```protected $except = [
    
]; ``` Where do I find the `config('session.cookie')` value to put in here?

Comment: it is come from config/session.php,  `cookie` key. And probably value will be `APP_NAME` from .ENV + `_session`. Like `myproject_session`. Or just print_r this expression `config('session.cookie')`.

Comment: I've done this. In this case my `APP_NAME` is `Laravel` so I put in `Laravel_session` in the `$except` array, but I am still not able to retrieve the session data from my Vue Js frontend. However when I use the REST client Insomnia it works

Comment: Try reload page and set this session value once again now in your frontend.

Comment: I've tried reloading the page, its still not working

Comment: Leave `$except` array empty and try very first answer(updated) with api middleware group setup. Works for me.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. I tried as you suggested in the edit of the answer above, still, getting the session returns null. I also tried putting all the values in `web` group in the `api` group as your suggested, now I get the error:  POST http://localhost:8000/api/set 419 (unknown status). Also what new configuration do you refer to when you say: " don't forget set your session variable again with new configuration."? Thanks

Comment: New configuration it is the changes in kernel.php.)) Remove csrf protection middleware to avoid 419 error.

Comment: I removed the csrf protection middleware and I no longer see the 419 error. But I still cannot view the session data. Also where can I find the session variable?